# Spectrahedron mesh lines

Tags: plotting, visualization

The following is a [spectrahedron](https://homepages.laas.fr/henrion/geolmi13/sturmfels.pdf) region plot using 3 eigenvalues for mesh functions. It takes 22 seconds and mesh line quality is quite poor, any tips on making it nicer?

Already using PlotPoints->50, so is there another setting for controlling number of evaluation points for mesh lines?

```
roots = Eigenvalues[{{1, p1, p2}, {p1, 1, p3}, {p2, p3, 1}}];
eig1 = Function[{p1, p2, p3}, Evaluate@roots[[1]]];
eig2 = Function[{p1, p2, p3}, Evaluate@roots[[2]]];
eig3 = Function[{p1, p2, p3}, Evaluate@roots[[3]]];
RegionPlot3D[
 Max@Eigenvalues@{{1, p1, p2}, {p1, 1, p3}, {p2, p3, 1}} < 2, {p1, -1,
   1}, {p2, -1, 1}, {p3, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MeshFunctions -> {eig1, eig2, eig3}]
```

[image]

PS, doing region plots for the three eigenvalues is informative, but doesn't seem to translate well into Mesh lines

```
ContourPlot3D[eig1[p1, p2, p3], {p1, -1, 1}, {p2, -1, 1}, {p3, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0]]
ContourPlot3D[eig2[p1, p2, p3], {p1, -1, 1}, {p2, -1, 1}, {p3, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0]]
ContourPlot3D[eig3[p1, p2, p3], {p1, -1, 1}, {p2, -1, 1}, {p3, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the numeric roots/eigenvalues are real, they come in increasing order. Maybe this, then?:

```
Quiet[
 RegionPlot3D[
  eig3[p1, p2, p3] < 2, {p1, -1, 1}, {p2, -1, 1}, {p3, -1, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 35, MeshFunctions -> {eig1, eig2}],
 Less::nord]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with `eig3` as a mesh function is that the surface coincides with a level set, up to a certain error. So the total range of `eig3` over the OP's surface, which should be `{2}` is in fact `{1.9991, 2.00002}`, and the surface approximation error is determining the mesh lines. ("The surface approximation error" comes from truncating the refinement of the polygonal mesh approximating the boundary `eig3[p1, p2, p3] == 2`.)

Comment: thanks, makes sense! Interesting that eig1 and eig2 mesh lines look identical even though region plots for those two functions look quite different

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yes, I noticed that, but it wasn't immediately obvious why last night. However, from the characteristic polynomial, one has $e_1+e_2+e_3 = 3=$ trace of the matrix. So if two of the eigenvalues are constant along a trajectory, so is the third.  You can save some time just specifying, say, `eig2` as a mesh function.

Answer (score 3):

Higher quality requires higher values for [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html), and specifying a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html). These will all increase the timing.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

roots = Eigenvalues[{{1, p1, p2}, {p1, 1, p3}, {p2, p3, 1}}];

{eig1, eig2, eig3} = Function[{p1, p2, p3}, Evaluate@#] & /@ roots;

Column[
 AbsoluteTiming[
  RegionPlot3D[
   Max@Eigenvalues@
      {{1, p1, p2}, {p1, 1, p3}, {p2, p3, 1}} < 2,
   {p1, -1, 1}, {p2, -1, 1}, {p3, -1, 1},
   PlotPoints -> 135,
   MaxRecursion -> 5,
   MeshFunctions -> {eig1, eig2, eig3},
   WorkingPrecision -> 30,
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]]
```

[image]